# Разное количество товаров в строке на разных устройствах

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

Здравствуйте. Сейчас на одной строке 3 товара на любых устройствах и начиная с планшета съезжают некоторые элементы, что не красиво и не допустимо и хотелось бы сделать по 2 товара, когда именно на планшете и смартфоне. Я смотрю, но нигде не вижу. Как это можно сделать в Joomla c Virtuemart?

Answer (score 0):

В 'Virtuemart' нет такого понятия - изменения количества продукта в строке в зависимости от того каким средством просматривают сайт, в настройах `Virtuemart` можно вставить только фиксированное число продуктов на строке. Если вам необходимо в планшетах или мобильных устройствах менять строение, можете использовать `css  media query` изменить `responsive` стили, как делать - читать например [ТУТ](https://habrahabr.ru/company/google/blog/173861/)

Comment: но насколько я понимаю для этого нужно изменить не только стили, но и js, ведь с помощью только стилей нельзя указать количество товаров или можно?

Comment: При респонсив вёрстке уже количество выводимых товаров не важно, т.к через css можно задать стили при которых продукты будут находится друг под другом, я советю прочитать больше об  адаптивном дизайне...